# Install php imap on docker container through dockerfile

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to modify my dockerfile so that it will install php-imap for php on our docker container

I have this:

```
RUN set -ex                      && \
apt-get update                   && \
apt-get install -y php-imap  && \
docker-php-ext-install php-imap
```

but I'm getting an error that it can't find php-imap?

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: Have you tried `RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl` and then `RUN docker-php-ext-install imap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 RUN   apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

Comment: For me wasn't enough that, I had to enable the extension in my php.ini extension=imap.so

Comment: [the importance of installing dependency libc-client-dev](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/imap.requirements.php)